# Volt Template Engine inside of jQuery

Tags: jquery, phalcon, volt

I have a (maybe) pretty unique problem. You can see the picture below for better comprehension.

The pieces of equipment in the select area are fetched in the controller and then I loop through them with Volt an echo them in `<option>` tags, as in the code below:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="0">No equipment</option>
    {% for item in equipment %}
    <option value="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The user can press the plus-Button to add another Equipment. The whole `<tr>` is cloned and appended via jQuery. The problem is, when I want to loop through the equipment pieces. The volt code is not parsed, but rather echoed explicitly by jQuery, as visible in the picture below.

The cloning code is this (pretty hacky, I guess, I don't know of a better alternative to this, though):

```
$('#addEquipment').bind('click', function() {
    var $div = $('tr[id^="rowEquipment"]:last');
    var num = parseInt($div.prop('id').match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
    var $clone = $div.clone().prop('id', 'rowEquipment' + num);
    var $equipment = '<td>'+
        '<div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-sm-1">'+
                '<p class="form-control-static">Equipment:</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-sm-3">'+
                '<select class="form-control">'+
                    '<option value="0">No equipment</option>'+
                    '{% for item in equipment %}'+
                    '<option value="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</option>'+
                    '{% endfor %}'+
                '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-sm-1">'+
                '<p class="form-control-static">Notes:</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-sm-3">'+
                '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Thickness mm / Weight kg">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-sm-4">'+
                '<button id="' + num + '" class="btn btn-default removeEquipment"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</td>';
    $div.after($clone.html($equipment));
    $('.removeEquiment').bind('click', function(evt) {
        var $id = $(evt.target).prop('id');
        var $removeEquipment = $('tr[id^="rowEquipment' + $id + '"]');
        $removeEquipment.remove();
    });
});
```

And here the picture:

[image]

Thank you for any advice!

**EDIT:**

The first solution from [yergo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4615331/yergo) (thank you) yields a `SyntaxError: invalid property id`, probably because `{% for item in equipment %}` is now treated as JavaScript and not as a string.

The second solution, when done like this:

```
var div = $('tr[id="cloneEquipment"]')[0];
var clone = div.cloneNode();
clone.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, div);
```

results in `TypeError: clone.parentNode is null`

Maybe important to mention (sorry, I forgot): the jQuery code is in a separate .js file

**EDIT 2**

I made an error: I was trying to append it to the parentNode of the cloned node, which obviously is bogus. Now, I'm this far:

Based on the second solution from yergo, I did some try&error in JSFiddle. Right now my solution looks like this:

```
var div = $('tr[id^="cloneEquipment"]');
var clone = div.clone();
clone.removeClass('hidden');
var cloneNode = clone[0].cloneNode();
div[0].parentNode.insertBefore(cloneNode, div[0]);
```

The cloning process seems to work, however it only clones the `<tr>` and not the contents of which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I came to the following working code. All the `clone.find()` commands can be ignored. This was a pure jQuery problem all along and had nothing to do with Volt or Phalcon. Like this, the volt code is parsed correctly:

```
$('#addEquipment').bind('click', function() {
    var div = $('tr[id^="rowEquipment"]:last');
    var num = parseInt(div.prop('id').match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
    var clone = div.clone();
    clone.prop('id', 'rowEquipment' + num);
    clone.find('.addEquipment').tooltip('disable');
    clone.find('.addEquipment').remove();
    clone.find('.helpEquipment').remove();
    clone.find('.removeEquipment').prop('id', num);
    clone.find('.removeEquipment').removeClass('hidden');
    $(div).after(clone);
    $('.removeEquipment').bind('click', function(evt) {
        var $id = $(evt.target).prop('id');
        var $removeEquipment = $('tr[id^="rowEquipment' + $id + '"]');
        $removeEquipment.remove();
    });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle for those interested:
[clickerino](https://jsfiddle.net/68wmwabc/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix this part:

```
'<select class="form-control">'+
    '<option value="0">No equipment</option>' +
    {% for item in equipment %}
        '<option value="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</option>' +
    {% endfor %}
'</select>' +
```

As long as this part of code is produced on server side and parsed via Volt engine, Volt control syntax should be threated as it would not appear on resulting output. So putting `'{% for item in equipment %}'+` is quite buggy.

Also, you can clone whole DOM nodes using JS. Try this code on this page:

```
var node = $('img[src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/35SUS.png"]')[0];
var nodeClone = node.cloneNode(true); // <- change here to 'true' for deep clone
node.parentNode.insertBefore(nodeClone, node);
```

You can keep whole `<tr>` in hidden element, and clone it fresh for new rows with simple JS.

**EDIT**: about [clonning](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp):

> Tip: Set the deep parameter value to true if you want to clone all descendants (children), otherwise false.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This results in `SyntaxError: invalid property id`, probably because `{% for item in equipment %}` is now treated as JavaScript and not as a string. If this doesn't work, I will try your other solution

Comment: Edited my initial post, the second solution also gives me an error, which to me is confusing, because your version works here

Comment: And a new edit :) I did it wrong as I was calling the parentNode of the cloned node. The cloning process seems to work, but it only clones the `<tr>` itself but it leaves out the contents of this `<tr>`, so, it just appends `<tr id="cloneEquipment1" class=""></tr>`